# Multiple Transactions in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: node.js, transactions, promise, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

## I need to make multiple transactions, fast

I'm developing a  **Node.JS**  application on Hyperledger Composer. I'm sending an insane amount of transactions per second (11,500) but it's fairly slow. I'm using the code from the Hyperledger Composer Tutorial and some examples from the web, but it seems to be that I can't make it any faster.

My model is fairly simple, it's the following:

```
participant Client identified by id {
  o String id
}

asset Wallet identified by id {
  o String id
  o Double balance
  --> Client owner
}
```

My script.js is the following

```
function transferFunds(transfer){
    //Transfer the funds
    transfer.from.balance -= transfer.amount;
    transfer.to.balance += transfer.amount;

    return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.Wallet')
    .then(function(assetRegistry){
        //persist the state of the Wallet
        assetRegistry.update(transfer.from);
        assetRegistry.update(transfer.to);
    });
     }
```

And I'm supposed to be transferring money between them, so my Node.js code to interact has the following logic:

1. Connect to Hyperledger Fabric
2. Get the Network Definition
3. Load the wallet that is transferring money
4. Load the wallet that is receiving money
5. Make the transfer
6. Execute the transaction

I feel my code is  *badly done* , it's fairly slow and it will usually overwhelm my Hyperledger Fabric instance. This is the NodeJS Code:

```
const makeTransaction = (fromID, toID, funds) => {
    let walletRegistry;
    let from;
    let to;

    businessNetworkConnection.connect(connectionProfile, businessNetworkIdentifier, participantId, participantPwd)
        .then((result) => {
            businessNetworkDefinition = result;
            return businessNetworkConnection.getAssetRegistry('org.acme.Wallet')
                .then(function (vr) {
                    walletRegistry = vr;
                    return walletRegistry.get(fromID);
                })
                .then(function (v) {
                    from = v;
                    return walletRegistry.get(toID);
                })
                .then(function (v) {
                    to = v;
                })
                .then(function () {
                    let serializer = businessNetworkDefinition.getSerializer();
                    let resource = serializer.fromJSON({
                        "$class": "org.acme.Transfer",
                        "amount": funds,
                        "from": {
                            "$class": "org.acme.Wallet",
                            "id": from.getIdentifier(),
                            "balance": from.balance,
                            "owner": "resource:org.acme.Client#" + from.owner.getIdentifier()
                        },
                        "to": {
                            "$class": "org.acme.Wallet",
                            "id": to.getIdentifier(),
                            "balance": to.balance,
                            "owner": "resource:org.acme.Client#" + to.owner.getIdentifier()
                        }
                    });
                    return businessNetworkConnection.submitTransaction(resource);
                });
        }).then((result) => {
            console.log(chalk.blue(' ------ All done! ------'));
            console.log('\n');
            return businessNetworkConnection.disconnect();
        }).catch(function (error) {
            businessNetworkConnection.disconnect();
            throw error;
        });
}
```

So basically, I'd like to know:

1. How could I improve it to allow multiple transactions without connecting multiple times?
2. Could my model be optimized to reduce the transaction size or to not have to preload both wallets?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see what was modeled for your `transfer` transaction.

assetRegistry.update() is done twice, perhaps an updateAll API call could be used ? -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/jsdoc/module-composer-client.AssetRegistry.html might help.

I can understand why your Node.js app would connect to the business network and interact ; but why wouldn't you just create your JSON transactions independently and just use REST to submit your transactions ? Eg using Node-Red https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/node-red.html to integrate / load your JSON from a file of transactions (if that's what you want to do, to transfer from and to wallets).  So to install Node Red use `npm install node-red -g` then launch it `node-red` and choose (from the palette) the Node red node 'node-red-contrib-fs’ under the Install tab (reads files from a directory on the file system). In the 'file pattern' use the pattern string `*.json` .

in answer to q2. Yes your model could be better modeled. This might be of use -> [When to call getAssetRegistry to update assets (and the participants equivalent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45428189/when-to-call-getassetregistry-to-update-assets-and-the-participants-equivalent)