# how to target a particular participant in hyperledger composer?

Tags: javascript, modeling, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

how can we target a particular participant, for example if I have list of traders as participants. And I want to write a transaction which enables transfers of funds between traders, how will I access individual traders from js file.

```
.cto file 
  { org.acme.exchange
     participant traders identified by email {

       o String email 
       o Double balance 
     }
    transaction pay{
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

your model (no namespace?) doesn't look right at first glance (from the extract you posted above). But there are examples here where you access the participant -> [When to call getAssetRegistry to update assets (and the participants equivalent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45428189/when-to-call-getassetregistry-to-update-assets-and-the-participants-equivalent) and here -> of how to reference Traders in your smart contract logic -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/trade-network/lib/logic.js and all sample networks with their sample smart contract logic here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/tree/master/packages/pii-network